# How to write a python function that returns date 30 days ago from given date

Tags: python, function, datetime

Hi I am new to python and I am trying to write a function that returns the date 30 days ago from a given date. My function has two parameters as seen below:

```
import datetime

def get_date_x_days_ago (x_days_ago, date_from = None):
    d = datetime.timedelta(days=x_days_ago)
    if date_from is None:
        date_from = datetime.today()
    else:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, "YYYY-mm-dd")

    return date_from - d

print(get_date_x_days_ago(x_days_ago=30, date_from="2020-11-11"))
```

I cant seem to get the function to work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the parsed date from `strptime` to the `date_from` variable.

Also, see https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime (under "Format Code List") for the corresponding date format codes, i.e. "%Y" denotes year with century.

```
import datetime

def get_date_x_days_ago (x_days_ago, date_from = None):
    d = datetime.timedelta(days=x_days_ago)
    if date_from is None:
        date_from = datetime.datetime.today()
    else:
        date_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, "%Y-%m-%d")
        # ^^^^ missing assignment

    return date_from - d

print(get_date_x_days_ago(x_days_ago=30, date_from="2020-11-11"))
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '2020-11-11' does not match format 'YYYY-mm-dd'   did you get this error?

Comment: what if I assign the date_from to none... ie    print(get_date_x_days_ago(x_days_ago=30, date_from=None)).... I get the following error:     date_from = datetime.today()
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'

Comment: what is the best way to test if the function works?

Comment: It should be `datetime.datetime.today()` - see documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today

Comment: You can write unit tests to test the function, and verify that the function returns a correct date based on several scenarios: `x_days_ago` is zero, `x_days_ago` is positive, `x_days_ago` is negative, `date_from` is None, `date_from` is well formatted ,`date_from` is not well-formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're finding a certain date from a date to x day before. So, first, convert your `date_from` to only date then subtract with `x_days`.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date
def get_date_x_days_ago(x_days_ago, date_from=None):
    return datetime.strptime(date_from, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - timedelta(x_days_ago) if date_from else date.today()-timedelta(x_days_ago)

print(get_date_x_days_ago(x_days_ago=30, date_from="2020-11-11"))
```

**Output**

```
get_date_x_days_ago(x_days_ago=30, date_from="2020-11-11")
2020-10-12

get_date_x_days_ago(x_days_ago=30)
2021-03-12
```

Comment: Missing space - `if datefromelse` -> `if date_from else`